# Local CouchDB on Mac Opens New Browser Tab Every 5 Seconds

Tags: mac-os-x, couchdb

I am doing some testing with CouchDB. I downloaded the CouchDB application on my Mac and ran it - it opened in my browser, I verified, created a database, added docs ... then I closed the application.

Next time I opened the CouchDB application, it opened a screen with the side menu but no other content (see attached image) and proceeds to open a new and identical tab every 5-10 seconds. The only way I can stop it is by closing the CouchDB application.

Any ideas about what is going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have another CouchDB running, then close it first (you might like to uninstall to stop it restarting on the next boot).  It seems like the CouchDB application fails when it can't get its expected port, but then restarts.  I uninstalled my CouchDB 1.6 (installed via homebrew) and am now able to run CouchDB 2.0 without this browser tabs problem!